# Docker port mapping

Tags: docker

Say I have two applications, each runs on a separate machine. Machine A runs module A, which opens a port 8080 to serve http request. Machine B runs module B, which sends http request to module A. Assuming module B doesn't know the IP address or port number of module A, and they share this information through say a Database table, which has the format of

service name | ip address | port number

when module A starts, it register itself and when module B starts, it looks up the table by the service name.

Now if both A and B are running inside a docker container, how would you achieve the same functionality programmatically so that everything is automated. What I would like to see is that I start a container A(by downloading its packaged image) and then B and the application will work the same way as before.

thanks!

Comment: See Docker documentation on container linking: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/

Comment: The thing is module B might not be running inside a container and they don't know where the other is until they check the database table.

Comment: You didn't outline that scenario in your original question. What you're missing is something called service discovery. An area of active research in the Docker community precisely because application components are more mobile. Checkout the following technologies and hopefully you'll get a feel what what is more useful to you: zookeeper, etcd, consul.